# ReferenceError: process is not defined at firebase-messaging-sw.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I **need to use .env** file **in the firebase-messaging-sw.js** located at public folder in the **ReactJs**. The .env file is located in project root folder and I need to use it in the firebase-messaging-sw.js without moving .env to another location. but When the environment variables was called in firebase-messaging-sw.js. I get the the reference error "process is not defined at firebase-messaging-sw.js" in **ReactJs**

This is my code in the firebase-messaging-sw.js.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId:  process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Is there an any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: React JS is front end. `process.env` object is provide in Node JS environment. However you can configure the Webpack to load the data from `process.env` using `dotenv` package. But when you build the react project, values will be replaced to the actual values so that anyone will able to see those keys using browser development tool.

Comment: I have .env file also in the src folder (root/src) , then isn't there a solution to this.

Comment: any update on the issue? i have the same .env file and get this error

Answer (score 2):

`firebase-messaging-sw.js` is executed on the client side, that's why you cannot access any `process` global variable.

Comment: I have .env file also in the src folder (root/src) , then isn't there a solution to this.